# Setpage don't work in wxpython2.9 webview when I use the pubsub

Tags: webview, wxpython, publish-subscribe

I am createing a app in windows use wxpython,and  I want to pubsub some data to create a html view,the pubsub data can print in cmd window,but when I setpage in webview,it don't work,can I use the webview to make this effect?
ps:if the webview can do this,and when click a link ,if it can pop a new frame to parse some data with this link ?

well,I am not describe my problem clearly,maybe I can describe it clearly by code:

in wxpython2.8,my code:

```
import time
import wx
import re
from threading import Thread
from wx.lib.pubsub import Publisher

import urllib2  
from win32gui import *
import win32gui
from wx.lib.wordwrap import wordwrap
import wx.html2 as webview
import lxml.html
import lxml.html.soupparser as soupparser


class ListenerThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start() 

    def findtitle(self):
        ........
        ........

    def find_window(self):
        title = self.findtitle()
        dlg=win32gui.FindWindow(None,title)
        return dlg

    def run(self):
        tempWindowName=win32gui.GetWindowText (self.find_window())
        while True:
            ........
            ........
            Publisher().sendMessage("update", info)
        time.sleep(0.1)

class InfoFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
       wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="title",size=(430, 700))
       panel = InfoPanel(self)
       style= self.GetWindowStyle()
       self.SetWindowStyle(style|wx.STAY_ON_TOP)

class InfoPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        .......

        self.browser= wx.html.HtmlWindow(self)
        Publisher().subscribe(self.updateDisplay)


        ......

    def updateDisplay(self, msg):
        t = msg.data
        self.browser.SetPage("%s"%t)


class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.infoFrame=InfoFrame()       
        self.SetTopWindow(self.infoFrame)
        self.infoFrame.Show(True)    
        return True

    def OnExit(self):
        wx.Exit()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(False)
    app.MainLoop()
```

the  info's structure like

```
<a href=....>text1</a><br><a href=......>text2</a><br>.....
```

it is parse from other website by lxml
and this code work,but I think this view is ugly,I want add some css style,and I think maybe I can open a new frame to show a some content also parse by the link when I click the link.

so,I search in google,and then found that maybe webview in wxpython2.9 can do this,and then,I change my code:

```
import time
import wx
import re
from threading import Thread
from wx.lib.pubsub import setupv1   
from wx.lib.pubsub import pub

import urllib2  
from win32gui import *
import win32gui
from wx.lib.wordwrap import wordwrap
import wx.html2 as webview
import lxml.html
import lxml.html.soupparser as soupparser

publisher = pub.Publisher()




class ListenerThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        """Init Worker Thread Class."""
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start() 

    def findtitle(self):
        ........
        ........

    def find_window(self):
        title = self.findtitle()
        dlg=win32gui.FindWindow(None,title)
        return dlg

    def run(self):
        tempWindowName=win32gui.GetWindowText (self.find_window())
        while True:
            ........
            ........
            Publisher().sendMessage("update", info)
        time.sleep(0.1)

class InfoPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        .......

        self.browser= webview.WebView.New(self)
        publisher.subscribe(self.updateDisplay)


        ......

    def updateDisplay(self, msg):
        t = msg.data
        page = "<html><body>"+"%s"%t+"</body></html>"
        self.browser.SetPage("%s"%t)


class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.infoFrame=InfoFrame()       
        self.SetTopWindow(self.infoFrame)
        self.infoFrame.Show(True)    
        return True

    def OnExit(self):
        wx.Exit()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(False)
    app.MainLoop()
```

but it show the error:

NotimpementedError:No matching function fo overoaded 'WebView_SetPage'

Thanks your time and any advise is appreciate .

Comment: Thans,bouke.I am not describe my problem clear,maybe I can describe it clear by code.

Answer (score 1):

According to docs `SetPage` function requires two arguments.

from `html2.py`:

> SetPage(self, String html, String baseUrl)
>   SetPage(self, InputStream html, String baseUrl)

from http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_web_view.html:

> `html`- The string that contains the HTML data to display.
>   `baseUrl`- URL assigned to the HTML data, to be used to resolve relative paths, for instance.

Just you can leave second empty.

```
import wx
import wx.html2


class AppFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(AppFrame, self).__init__(parent)

        self.html_view = wx.html2.WebView.New(self)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.html_view, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()

    frame = AppFrame(None)
    frame.html_view.SetPage("<html><body>Hello World</body></html>", "")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```